# Review the Design of My RDBMS (MySQL 5.6)

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6

I am developing a web application for conducting Phishing Awareness testing ([Github Repo](https://github.com/SafePhish/SafePhish_App)). I have been getting tons of feedback on [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A110282%20is%3Aquestion) to this project. It can be referenced if you want to get a more in-depth understanding of this project.

That being said, I am working at modifying and cleaning up my database to increase its efficiency for the server, readability for a DBA, and usability by the user, all while reducing the required overhead. Below is my proposed design of my database. Any suggestions as to the design of my database is appreciated.

To explain the project at a high level, I have a Graphical User Interface (GUI) that will allow `users` to log on and send emails out. These emails will be stored inside of organization units called `projects`. The user does not define who the email gets sent to. An algorithm is used to decide whether a `mailing_list` item is a valid recipient. If they are, an email is sent and it is logged in the `sent_email` table. Each email contains a webbug which references a public facing URL. This URL inserts data into the `website_tracking` and `email_tracking` tables based on where the request came from (the URL path).

```
+--------------------------+
| Tables                   |
+--------------------------+
| users                    |
| mailing_list             |
| sent_email               |
| projects                 |
| website_tracking         |
| email_tracking           |
| report_tracking          |
| default_email_settings   |
+--------------------------+

users
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| USR_UserId          | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| USR_Username        | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| USR_Email           | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| USR_FirstName       | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| USR_LastName        | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| USR_Initial         | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| USR_Password        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| USR_CanCreateUsers  | tinyint          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mailing_list
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| MGL_Id              | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| MGL_Username        | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MGL_Email           | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MGL_FirstName       | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MGL_LastName        | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MGL_UniqueURLId     | varchar          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

sent_email
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SML_EmailId         | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| SML_UserId          | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| SML_ProjectId       | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| SML_SentTimestamp   | Timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

projects
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PRJ_ProjectId          | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| PRJ_ProjectName        | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PRJ_ProjectDescrip     | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PRJ_ProjectAssignee    | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| PRJ_ProjectStart       | Timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PRJ_ProjectLastActive  | Timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PRJ_ProjectStatus      | tinyint          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

website_tracking
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| WBS_WTrackId           | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| WBS_WIp                | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| WBS_WHost              | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| WBS_WBrowserAgent      | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| WBS_WReqPath           | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| WBS_UserId             | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| WBS_ProjectId          | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| WBS_WAccessTimestamp   | Timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

email_tracking
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| EML_ETrackId           | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| EML_EIp                | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EML_EHost              | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EML_UserId             | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| EML_ProjectId          | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| EML_EAccessTimestamp   | Timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

report_tracking
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RPT_RTrackId           | int              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | AI    |
| RPT_RIp                | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| RPT_RHost              | varchar          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| RPT_UserId             | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| RPT_ProjectId          | int              | NO   | FK  | NULL    |       |
| RPT_RAccessTimestamp   | Timestamp        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

default_email_settings
+-------------------+------------------+------+--------+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key    | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+------------------+------+--------+---------+-------+
| DFT_UserId        | int              | NO   | PRI FK | NULL    |       |
| DFT_MailServer    | varchar          | NO   |        | NULL    |       |
| DFT_MailPort      | varchar          | NO   |        | NULL    |       |
| DFT_Username      | int              | NO   |        | NULL    |       |
| DFT_CompanyName   | int              | NO   |        | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+------------------+------+--------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: No foreign keys defined? The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` is far more useful than DESCRIBE TABLE by the way.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ while I do agree with you there, I haven't yet created this database with these new fields. This is purely based on whiteboard drawing right now and I'm just checking my work. As far as foreign keys, FK is foreign key but I didn't want to drag the data to multiple rows so I left it out of extra. If you think it should be shown, I can add it in.

Comment: Use SHOW CREATE TABLE name\G - gives a good format for copying and pasting. Your schema looks OK - but this is too "big" a question for here - you need to start working on your system and as more specific problems arise, you can ask about them here. There's nothing obviously wrong - but starting to code is what's needed now.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed the `FK`s. For a `[database-design]` question, I expect this info to be in the question, as Verace and I advised, with SHOW CREATE TABLE. It still may be closed as out of topic but lets see.

Comment: @Vérace: That's kind of what I'm looking for. If you look at some of the stuff on the CR linked questions, I've got about 2 months of work on this project already. Now I'm just redesigning my database to be better designed and utilized. However, as both of you and ypercube have said, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. I would but this is whiteboard drawing so there is no built database to query from. We'll see what happens, but hopefully I can at least just get some sort of broad suggestion on improvements to the structure.

Comment: You might be trying too hard :-). With this sort of project, it's impossible to give a definitive answer until you've got a prototype - and believe me, there'll be problems with any prototype. It's good that you're taking the design phase seriously (I've worked on systems where the "back of an envelope approach would have been considered sophisticated), but there's a law of diminishing returns here. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: You will eventually find that prefixing column names with table names is clutter, not useful.

Comment: @RickJames: I can see your reasoning behind that, but when you've got field names that get reused in multiple tables it is usually easier to prefix. If you don't you can't do joins without complex views and procedures.

Comment: (my preference:)  `SELECT mgl.email ... FROM mailing_list AS mgl JOIN ... ON mgl.id = ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think the passwords would normally be kept in a separate table and encrypted. Also you might need a column for number of failed password attempts with a limit and something to reset the value every 30 minutes etc.

I am guessing you would also have a stored procedure for the GUI to access passwords to prevent injection.

Comment: The password is hashed and uses a hash_veirfy function to check if it is valid. This function also checks for injection. Thanks though!